# Is TempData in ASP.NET MVC secure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, tempdata

I want to know about security of tempdata in ASP.NET MVC in the following scenario.

If one user is logged in and there is data passed to tempdata and it is we are keeping for next request or we are not reading it so it keeps value in tempdata. If another user logged in, then will that tempdata value also be available to the second user?

Comment: No. `TempData` use `Session` (its user specific)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TempData` uses *by default* `Session`*. Therefore it is as safe as a session can be.

A session is individual for every user, so yes.

[Session Hijacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking) is one problem for a session, but since `TempData` is only valid for one request, I do not see any problems.

<sub>* Note it is possible to create a own [`ITempDataProvider`](https://brockallen.com/2012/06/11/cookie-based-tempdata-provider/) (Credits to [NightOwl888](https://stackoverflow.com/users/181087/nightowl888)). In this case, you need to evaluate, if your provider is secure.</sub>

Comment: Technically, `TempData` uses `Session` *by default*. You can change the provider to use another storage mechanism. For example, here is a [cookie-based TempData provider](https://brockallen.com/2012/06/11/cookie-based-tempdata-provider/).